# Rotate pages of pdf in c#

Tags: c#, pdf

Hello all I am creating an application using `C#`in which I am getting some pdf files with some Landscape and some portrait pages, now I want to convert landscape pages into portrait, I saw some articles but every article is asked to buy license, is there any way we can do convert the landscape pages into portrait without any license?

Comment: By *convert landscape pages into portrait* do you mean rotating the page so that it is sideways? Or do you want is contents to reflow to properly fill the changed paper size unrotated?

Comment: @mkl I want to rotate the page like changing portrait into landscape or visa versa

Comment: Merely rotating the whole page should be possible with any general purpose PDF library. What is your PDF library of choice?

Comment: I am actually using groupdocs and my license expired on 20.4 version and pdf rotation added in 21.7 version